# How to make this grammar LL(1)

Tags: parsing, grammar

I want to know if it would be possible to transform this grammar to LL(1). This is the grammar:

```
A -> B
   | C

B -> a 
   | a ';'

C -> a D
   | a D ';'

D -> ';' a
   | D ';' a
```

Comment: That's a much more complicated grammar than necessary for this simple language. Regardless, you can make it LL(1) by [removing left recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_recursion#Removing_left_recursion) and then [left factoring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LL_parser#Left_Factoring)

Comment: In [DCG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Definite_clause_grammar) notation, A -> B | C could be written as `a --> b;c.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the same grammar but simpler:
A -> a | a ';' | a ';' A

It still not LL(1). But removing left factor now it is LL(1):
A -> a B B -> ε | ';' C C -> ε | A

Answer (score 1):

Since this language is regular ( `a; | a(;a)+;?` ), then yes, it would be possible.

Not sure if I'm using the right syntax, but the language is basically `a;` (using A->B) or any string that starts with an `a`, followed one or more `;a` pairs, optionally adding another `;` on the end.

Comment: Thanks, you are right. Now, do you know how to transform it?

Comment: Well, I turned it into an RE, so I probably do.  If you want help in doing so, show what you have tried.

Comment: I forgot another possibility in rule B. Now it is well written. I hope it's not a problem. I tried to remove the left recursion in rule B but the grammar still not LL(1).

Comment: This is what I tried:
A → B
| C .
B → a ';' .
C → a D
| a D ';' .
D → ';' a D1 .
D1 → ';' a D1
| .